# was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Not sure how to fix this error? Can I get AWS to serve my S3 content via https (SSL)?

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/thing/index' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2-54-228-444-239.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/socket.io/1/?t=14543333333'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure this url should be :

```
http://ec2-54-228-444-239.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/socket.io/1/?t=14543333333
```

as

```
https://ec2-54-228-444-239.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/socket.io/1/?t=14543333333
```

Comment: You can also serve S3 assests via SSL. It depends upon developemnt language. And another thing , if  your asset was serving over http and if you are running site over https , then it will raises a Mixed Content issue.

Comment: If your site was running over HTTPS and all your assets , js ,css should run over HTTPS. Otherwise it will be a mixed content error.

Comment: I understand the issue. My site is running over HTTPS, but assets on EC2 are all HTTP. What I don't know how to do is get EC2 to use https. If I hit my real http://ec2 url above ( it says welcome to socket.io). If I try my original URL with https:// it says page not available, because EC2 won't allow me select https instead of http.